# How can I automatically send a text through Messages.app regardless of recipient's OS?

Tags: applescript, sms, imessage

My goal is to send automated texts on macOS to a phone number in a FileMaker record using FileMaker's `Perform AppleScript` step (so `tell app "FileMaker"` is not in the script below).

These are contacts not in Contacts.app's database, so `tell app "Messages" to send ...` isn't an option, at least not directly.

Here's my current script.

```
set _delay to 0.5

set _phone_number to repetition 1 of cell "APPLESCRIPT_PIPE" of layout "DEV"
set the clipboard to _phone_number

set _msg to repetition 2 of cell "APPLESCRIPT_PIPE" of layout "DEV"

tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Messages"
    set frontmost to true
    keystroke "n" using {command down}
    delay _delay

    keystroke "v" using {command down}
    delay _delay

    keystroke return
    delay _delay

    tell text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window 1
      set value to _msg
      delay _delay

      keystroke return

    end tell

  end tell
end tell

activate
```

This works flawlessly when sending a text to an iPhone, but when the recipient is using a phone without iMessages, sometimes it doesn't get delivered.

[image]

Clicking the "Not Delivered" button followed by "Try Again" sends it via SMS.

`tell app "Messages" to send...` works if the phone number is in the Contacts.app database, at least it has on a few that I've tested, but adding a contact to the database and then attempting to send that contact a text does not work. Here's the script I tried:

```
tell application "Contacts"
  set _person to make new person with properties¬
    {first name:"Bruce", last name:"Wayne"}
  tell _person
    make new phone at end of phones of _person with properties¬
      {label:"mobile", value:"1234567890"}
  end tell
  save
end tell

tell application "Messages"
  send "Chuck's test" to buddy "1234567890" of service "SMS"
end tell
```

The contact does get added to the database, but the message does not send. No error is generated, it just doesn't send.

Anyone have an idea on either how to make sure texts to Android phones go through the first time or, as a fallback, a way to detect when they don't?

Answer (score 1):

I have develop a Filemaker script that works for me to send messages via iMessage or SMS (without the need to add the buddy to the contact app). As you are familiar to Filemaker, you can

1. Set a variable $Message with the text to be sent
2. Set a variable $PhoneNumber with the phonenumber (filtered by "+0123456789")
3. Use the Perform Applescript step with a calculated Applescript like the following one:

`"display dialog \"Send SMS?\" default answer \"" & $Message & "\" buttons {\"Cancel\", \"OK\"} default button 2" & ¶ &
    "copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}" & ¶ &
    "if button_pressed is \"OK\" then" & ¶ &
    "tell application \"Messages\"" & ¶ &
    "send text_returned to buddy \"" & $PhoneNumber & "\" of service \"SMS\" " & ¶ &
    "end tell" & ¶ &
    "end if"`

I have added a dialog box to be able to edit the automatically formatted message in my Filemaker Database. Next step form me is to be able to add an ical event in the sent sms... Any idea is welcome ;-)